# source_sink error in prolog using rdf_load

Tags: prolog, rdf

I want to load rdf url from this rule:

```
getActorFilms(Actor_Name,Films):-
    my_replace(Actor_Name, ' ', '_', Correct_Syntax_Of_Actor_Name),
    string_concat('http://dbpedia.org/data/',Correct_Syntax_Of_Actor_Name, URL_TO_LOAD),
    string_concat(URL_TO_LOAD,'.rdf',RDF_URL),
    rdf_load(RDF_URL),
    rdf(Films, 'http://dbpedia.org/ontology/starring', Object)
.
```

when the input is e.g. for an example 'Hugh Jackman'
it tells the error:

```
ERROR: [Thread pdt_console_client_0_Default Process] source_sink `http://dbpedia.org/data/Hugh_Jackman.rdf' does not exist
```

I'm really concerned about the **`** character between http and `source_sink`
I think it should be `'`
although the url is correct, so what to do with that error?

Comment: The backtick is fine. Are you sure you loaded `library('semweb/rdf_http_plugin')`? Trying to call `rdf_load` before loading it will cause this error when reading from an http server.

Comment: To clarify that "the backtick is fine":  single and double quotation marks are actually balanced in typography (“ ” ‘ ’), even though most keyboards don't have these characters.  When writing in plan text, one way of simulating this is to use a backtick (`\``) as a left single quotation mark and a single quote `'` as a right single quotation mark.  It appears that's what this error message uses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass an atom to `rdf_load`, not a string. This behavior (the misleading error message, not accepting a string) is probably a bug.

This works for me:

```
?- use_module(library('semweb/rdf_db')).
true.

?- use_module(library('semweb/rdf_http_plugin')).
true.

?- rdf_load('http://dbpedia.org/data/Hugh_Jackman.rdf').
% Parsed "http://dbpedia.org/data/Hugh_Jackman.rdf" in 0.02 sec; 371 triples
true.

?- string_to_atom(S, 'http://dbpedia.org/data/Hugh_Jackman.rdf'), rdf_load(S).
ERROR: source_sink `http://dbpedia.org/data/Hugh_Jackman.rdf' does not exist
```

I hope this solves your problem.